# What does the wealth distribution among India's lower caste and upper caste look like?

Tags: india, demographics, inequality

It is well known that [UC Hindus own 41% of assets in India](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20much%20%25%20of%20UC%20own%20wealth%20in%20India&oq=how%20much%20%25%20of%20UC%20own%20wealth%20in%20India&aqs=chrome..69i57.3758j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when being about [30% of the population](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/school-enrolment-data-indicates-45-obcs-19-dalits-in-india/articleshow/84877162.cms), and, the remaining 59% of assets is distributed among the 70% of the UCs. My question is, how exactly does this distribution among the caste it self look like?

So for example, I am looking for a bell curve of asset owned in y-axis with population on x axis.

**Motivation:** I ask this because, An argument against caste based reservation is that the majority of the 59% wealth is located in a very small subset of the LC category, and, hence they form a 'neo-upper-caste'. Hence, to bring equality, we should do based reservation only on economic status rather than caste.

Comment: The best would probably to not use too large bins but simply rank people in India by their share of the total wealth and then have a full distribution and split into castes or other groups. 41% for 30% doesn't sound very inequal.

Comment: How do you mean by large bin? @Trilarion You need to consider India's population. There is a lot of people in that remaining 70%.

Comment: Upper caste and lower caste is two very large bins. The conclusion you want to draw is probably about averages within that bin. But in reality everyone has a different wealth. It gives a more complete picture to look at full distributions than only at average values.

Comment: Right, I edited so it asks both distribution of upper and LC

Comment: This blog explores the issue comprehensively in a great many individual blog posts from almost every imaginable angle. http://datastories.in/blog/

Comment: "the remaining 59% of assets is distributed among the 70% of the UCs." Do you mean LC? And I assume that "UC" is short for "Upper Caste", but it took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: @Trilarion Caste-bins are very different from simply ranking people. Trying to measure inequality on an individual level gets into all sorts of issues, such as wives who don't have any wealth under their own name, people in their twenties who have high income but low wealth because they haven't had time to build up their net worth, etc.

Comment: Yea @Acccumulation that is right

Comment: Also much less concentrated than in the U.S. where the top third own 79% of the nation's assets. https://www.pewresearch.org/social-trends/2020/01/09/trends-in-income-and-wealth-inequality/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a lot of inequality within each caste community. Here is a summary of data from a research paper by Nitin Kumar Bharti for World Inequality Lab. This is only paper I could find on this subject that provides detailed data within each caste. It shows how much % of assets the top X% people own in 2012.

| Caste | Top 1% | Top 5% | Top 10% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FC/OC | 29.4% | 47.6% | 60% |
| SC | 14.4% | 33.5% | 46.7% |
| ST | 19.5% | 38.93% | 51.4% |
| OBC | - | - | 52% |

Here is a direct quote from section `5.3.1 Top Deciles` of the paper reg this

> "Within Forward Caste, Top 1% within FC owned almost 13.6% of the total FC wealth in 2002 which increased to 29.4% in 2012. Top 5% owned 32% in 2002 which increased to 47.6% in 2012. And Top 10% now owns 60% of the total FC wealth. This is a drastic change in ten years is which needs more enquiry. The  inequality within FC group is the highest."
>
> Within ST, Top 1% owned 10.7% of total ST wealth in 1991, which increased to 15.1% in 2002 and further to above 19.5% in 2012. Top 5% share of total ST wealth increased from 27.7% in 1991 to 38.93% in 2012. Top 10% of share increased from 40.3% in 1991 to 51.4% in 2012. This caste group has seen a consistent rise in within caste inequality
>
> Within SC, Top 1% owned 11.9% of total SS wealth in 1991, which decreased to 10.83% in 2002 and then increased to 14.4% in 2012. Top 5% share of total SC wealth increased from 30.3% in 1991 to 33.5% in 2012. Top 10% of SC share increased from 43.6% in 1991 to 46.7% in 2012. SC has the lowest level of within caste inequality in terms of top decile share.
>
> Within OBC, Top 10% share increased from 46.2% in 2002 to 52% in 2012.

Reference:

1. [Wealth Inequality, Class and Caste in India, 1961-2012](https://wid.world/document/n-k-bharti-wealth-inequality-class-and-caste-in-india-1961-2012/)

Comment: Which caste do the abbreviations the researchers use apply to? Which one is the Brahmins, the Kshatriyas, the Vaishas, etc?

Comment: @nick012000 The one used by the Indian government to classify and group castes. The reasearch paper linked has full details reg this.